# Macro stops after using button twice

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a button that copies and inserts a new row. The problem here is that I can only call the macro twice before it gives me a 400 error. Any suggestions on how to solve the issue?

```
Sub AddNewRow()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    r.Offset(-2).EntireRow.Copy
    r.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
    r.Offset(-2).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

*** Edit ***

I created a delete button. As long as I don't create more then 2 rows everything works. When I create 3 rows in sequence it crashes.

```
Sub DeleteLastRow()  
  
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    r.Offset(-2).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

***Edit***
Tried it on another sheet in the same document with the same data. There it works perfectly. What kind of setting could screw up this VBA? No other VBA present in the document.

***Edit***
Problem solved. There was some stray text in (XFC;1048574). After deleting the text the function worked.

Comment: Seems the macro works, but may be doing the same again and again on the same cell.

Comment: The strange part is that I have multiple buttons all doing the same on different parts and if I press any two of them once or one twice it gives me the 400 error. They perform their task perfectly before the third press.

Comment: what line does arise the error when it fails?

Comment: It just gives me a "400". It doesn't show any specifics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Had some text in XFC:1048574. After deleting the text the problem was resolved.